# Can't reach simple express app from remote IP

Tags: express, router

I have pretty much the simplest possible express app:

```
var express = require('express')
var app = express()

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
  res.send('Hello World!')
})

app.listen(3000, function () {
  console.log('Example app listening on port 3000!')
})
```

I want to access it from my remote IP, I can see it from `localhost:3000` and [canyouseeme](http://www.canyouseeme.org) says my ports are open. I have disabled firewall in windows, but I still can't access it from `78.xx.xxx.138:3000`

Comment: Do you get a 503/504?

Comment: I am not, I can't seem to reach the server at all from my browser. However  if I tried using `ngrok` to make my server available for remote, it threw 502, telling that host actively refused connection. Which would mean that it's port/fw problem, but I've disabled firewall and opened my ports...